# Python loop through json array value error

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a json file with some data in it.

```
[
 {
   "@timestamp": "2021-05-07 15:01:19",
   "message": "hello",
   "name": "hi",
   "userID": "001"
 },
 {
   "@timestamp": "2021-05-07 15:01:19",
   "message": "hello",
   "name": "hi",
   "userID": "001"
 }
]
```

I want to loop through it and output its content but I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

my code is this:

```
import json
with open('final_result.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    for v in data.values():
        print(v)
```

can somebody help me to understand why I am getting this error and how to solve it?

thank you much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json file consists of 2 json objects. Each json object is equivalent to a dictionary in python. The load function is returning a list of dictionaries. Traverse over the list of dictionaries to get the desired output.

```
import json

with open('final_result.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    for v in data:
        for value in v.values():
            print(value)
```